# Синонимизировать [int] и [integer]?

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Существуют метки [int](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/int) и [integer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integer), которые, судя по всему, означают одно и то же. В метке [int](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/int) 127 вопросов (описание есть), в [integer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integer) — 34 вопроса (описания нет). Имеет смысл их синонимизировать (в пользу [int](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/int), разумеется)?

Comment: А может в пользу [tag:integer] как более полного слова? Или даже сделать 1С-style [tag:целое] 

Comment: @αλεχολυτ нет, только не 1С!

Comment: В некоторых языках (например в java) это не совсем одно и то же...

Comment: @Зонтик, но и то, и другое относится к целым числам)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Синонимизировал и объединил
[integer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integer) → [int](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/int).

Comment: А теперь надо переименовать в `integer`. Может быть расскажут [как.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391836/339911)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ зачем?

Comment: а почему вдруг СОКРАЩЕНИЕ должно быть основной меткой?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ потому что именно его сообщество выбирало чаще для своих вопросов и у него было описание. Почему сначала ничего не делаешь, а затем начинаешь спорить с результатами, да еще так принципиально? Если это экзистенциальной важности вопрос, ведь его мог же обработать сразу, а не оставлять комментарий под вопросом, верно?

Comment: описание — потому что стандартный тип во многих ЯП; Выбирало — по той же причине, и т.к. короче. При наличии синонима, как ты понимаешь, длина не важна, будет автоматом подставляться целевая метка. Кстати, я еще вспомнил про [ассемблерный int](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Int_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_x86)). Так что могут быть нюансы. P.S. чтобы обрабатывать надо быть уверенным, а у меня были и есть сомнения.